# How can I show specific products on homepage in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, products, category-products, home-page

How can I show specific products on homepage? It has to be client friendly to do in CMS. I tried displaying a category then changing the sort order on products in category.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can create an attribute say "Is Home" with type "Yes/No"
2. assign that attribute to attribute set
3. assign "Yes" to some products.
4. Create a new widget on CMS Home page with following condition. See image.

[image]

**Note:** in "Conditions" you will need to select "Is Home" Yes