# How to get feature product on home page in magento 2 customization?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento2.3.1

How to get all **featured product** on home page in magento 2 ?

Customization throw how to get all featured products ? Please tell me step by step guide what file to create what to do ?

Comment: what is the criteria of featured product ?how you differentiate them to other ?

Comment: Please check : https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/254928/how-can-i-show-specific-products-on-homepage-in-magento-2/254930#254930

Comment: @pawan  one attribute create featured product so  get all featured products only home page show ? how to get featured product?

Comment: check my answer in above comment, it has same requirement

Comment: yes I know this way is right but i have customize and get featured products so ple tell me

Comment: do you want to customise `phtml`(design) ?

Comment: Pawan I am show only featured products on home page with customization throw ? You have idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **Magento 2 Product Slider Extension**. Its free of cost. And show featured products on home page.
You can read these user guide to get your requirements [User Guide](https://docs.mageplaza.com/product-slider-m2/)

There is many options and this extension also fulfill your requirements. 
[image: Features products]

Comment: Arsian Thanks for guide me but I have cutomize this features products how to codeing throw

Comment: what you want to customize ? feature products or any thing else?

Comment: only show home page feature products (get all feature products )code throw

Comment: you can get using this extension ,, i have done it already.

Comment: hafiz I know also I used but how to customize ?